# Как сервисы аналитики определяют пол/возраст/страну пользователя Instargam?

Tags: instagram, статистика

В api не нашел такой информации, может пользуются сторонними ресурсами?

Comment: О каких именно сервисах аналитики идет речь? Что вы пробовали с  **Instagram-API** вытащить?

Comment: К примеру livedune.ru может определять город

Comment: У Вас задание сделать что-то типа указанного Вами сайта? Если да, то напишите условие задачи и что у Вас не получается.

Comment: У меня не получается определить город и пол пользователя (любого)

Comment: Город можно примерно определить по геометкам фотографий, а пол по фото + имени, но мне кажется, что можно как-то проще получить эти данные

Comment: Пол по фото сложно определять программно, так как кто-то может собаку или гамбургер  вместо авы залить. Локацию публикации можно определить https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/locations/
 Но не адрес проживания юзверя.

Comment: Можно посмотреть историю локаций и на основе самой популярной предположить город, так же на основе других данных мы можем только предполагать, вопрос как же сервисы определяют эти данные, тоже на основе данных или есть другой способ?